# How do I install awesome WM on Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: awesome-wm

I have installed awesome via

```
$ apt-get install awesome
```

That adds awesome to the login screen's sessions menu but when I attempt to create an awesome session the screen goes briefly blank and then reverts to login.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Installing AwesomeWM is done using `apt-get install awesome`. There is thousand of people using AwesomeWM in Ubuntu and it works for them. If AwesomeWM does not start, it can be because of one of the following reason:

- A custom config in `~/.config/awesome` uses LGI in a way that isn't safe and cause a segmentation fault.
- Multiple incompatible PPAs have been installed and applications can no longer start.
- The config in `/etc/xdg/awesome` has been modified and its syntax is invalid.
- A driver issue causes a crash (in that case adding `--no-argb` to the session command may help`.
- X11 itself crashes, see `/var/log` and `~/.xsession-errors` for details
- The session file is invalid and tries to start AwesomeWM without starting X11 first or something like that.